# Colspan and rowspan in mat-table

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have this table in standard HTML and I want to convert it to a MatTable.
But I have some troubles to understand how the mat-table works, especially with my dataset which is not classic.

Here is my table at the moment :[image]

The group1 and group2 are generated (there can be more groups), I have my header like this:

```
{ 
Group1: 
   firstRow: [Y, B, ...]
   secondRow: [Y, M, ...]
Group2:
   ...
}
```

And I have the same pattern for my data, so currently I have some ngfor in my table to render them.

Do you have any idea to how can I transform this into a mat table ? I can't find a solution to make my header.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{ display: 'none' }">
        Date
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
        {{ data.date| date: "E, dd/MM/yyyy" }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{ display: 'none' }">
        Time
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
        {{ utils.timeToString(data.time) }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>



    <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="3">Date</th>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Time">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="3">
        Departure time
      </th>
    </ng-container>

    <tr
      mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="['Date', 'Time']"
    ></tr>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
```

Here is also what I try to made the groups line:

```
 <ng-container
      *ngFor="let group of data.groups"
      [matColumnDef]=" ?? what to put here "
 >
   <th
     mat-header-cell
     *matHeaderCellDef
     mat-sort-header
     [attr.colspan]="group.letters.length"
   >
     {{ group.name }}
   </th>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: add some working code and where you stuck?

Comment: I just can't achieve the header, I don't understand how to make a header with colspan and rowspan, I'm just able to do a one-line header

Comment: so far what you did? can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I add what I have, but this is just the first columns, I don't understand how to handle the double ng-for to made the rest of the header